# apoc.index.search returning OR results instead of performing an AND

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I have set up a full text index on one field using the following apoc query

```
CALL apoc.index.addAllNodes("CompName", {Basic_company_data:["CompanyName"]})
```

It seems to create the index correctly. If I then run this query

```
call apoc.index.search("CompName", "swaythling~") YIELD node as n return n
```

I get five results, which is expected.

If I then run the same query but with + housing

```
call apoc.index.search("CompName", "swaythling~ + housing~") YIELD node as n return n
```

I get 100 nodes returned, not the one node I was expecting. This seems to be the total number of nodes with swaythling OR housing in the company name, when I am trying to get the results for swaythling AND housing.

I can get the correct results by doing two apoc calls but I fell the and is something I should be able to do.

Have I done something wrong in setting up the index or am I missing something from the index search itself?

Comment: The underlying index is lucene, and I think `+` indicates the next token has to be present, I don't think it means AND. Have you tried using `&&` instead?

Comment: No I hadn't tried it and yes it was the answer.. thank you

Comment: Nice. I added my comment as an answer and linked to the lucene documentation.

Comment: FYI: Boolean algebra uses `+` for `OR` and `*` for `AND`. For example `x*y=1`  both have to be 1 same in an actual multiplication. This also works for `OR` `x+y>=1` at least one variable has to be 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying index is [lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#AND), and I think `+` indicates the next token has to be present, I don't think it means AND. Have you tried using `&&` instead?`